# 4D Tensor Shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was reading a Machine Learning book and came across this in the CNN chapter.

> The weights of a convolutional layer are represented as a 4D tensor of
> shape [fh, fw, fn′, fn]. The bias terms of a convolutional layer are
> simply represented as a 1D tensor of shape [fn]. Where fh is the heigher of the receptive field and fw is the width of the receptive field. fn' is the number of feature maps in the previous layer and fn is the number of feature maps in the current layer.

I am trying to understand what each number in the given order signifies. Is it creating a rank 4 matrix where each entry represents the weight connecting an output neuron from the previous layer with specified feature map and location in the receptive field to the current ouput neuron?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fn'`:

It represents number of channels in previous layer which also indirectly specifies `depth`(or channels) of each `kernels` in current layer.

`fn`:

It represents number of feature maps in current layer i.e. number of different `kernels` in current layer. Because each kernel outputs single channel.

`fw`:

It represents `kernel` width.

`fh`:

It represents `kernel` height.

Suppose  `[fh, fw, fn′, fn] = [3, 3, 10, 20]` then layer(weight) will be of size `20x10x3x3`. Each kernel will be of size `10x3x3` (where `3x3` is spacial and 10 is depth) and there will be 20 such kernels. These kernels operate on previous `20` feature maps to output `10` feature maps.

And each entry in this `4d` matrix representing `weight` will be shared. It `doesn't` connect neurons `one to one` because of `convolution`. Convolution's main advantages itself is `parameter sharing` and receptive field/local connectivity.

Comment: Great explanation! Some cool further reading if you are learning about CNNs @pineapple69. [Gauge CNN](https://www.quantamagazine.org/an-idea-from-physics-helps-ai-see-in-higher-dimensions-20200109/)

Comment: Also it doesnt connect neurons one to one because of overlapping receptive fields?